# Intel Wi-Fi adapter randomly quits working

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, services, network-adapter

I'm using an Acer Aspire M5-583P-6428 running Windows 8.1. For quite a while, I've been having a strange issue with my Wi-Fi adapter. Said adapter is a built-in Intel Dual Band Wireless-N 7260. The problem I've been having is as follows.

- I'll be using my computer in some way, usually playing games or browsing the Internet.
- Out of nowhere, I am disconnected from the Internet.
- I open up the Networks flyout and see that my computer says I am still connected to the network, but the "Limited" status is displayed. Additionally, the switch used to toggle Wi-Fi on and off is no longer present and toggling Airplane Mode does nothing.
- I open up the Event Viewer and find the following system error:

> Source - Service Control Manager
>
> Event ID - 7023
>
> "The Network Connection Broker service terminated with the following error: An invalid argument was supplied."

Sometimes, I will get this instead:

> Source - Service Control Manager
> Event ID - 7031
> "The Network Connection Broker service terminated unexpectedly.  It has done this 1 time(s).  The following corrective action will be taken in 5000 milliseconds: Restart the service."

Which then results in:

> Source - Service Control Manager
> Event ID - 7032
> "The Service Control Manager tried to take a corrective action (Restart the service) after the unexpected termination of the Network Connection Broker service, but this action failed with the following error:
> An instance of the service is already running."

*However, it is determinable that the service had not restarted.* I have tried manually restarting the Network Connection Broker in Services, but to no avail.

There is one solution that I have found to work, but it is time-consuming and sometimes must be repeated multiple times. The procedure is simply to disable the Intel Wi-Fi adapter in the Device manager, wait a couple minutes, and re-enable it. However, once again, *this procedure is not always convenient if I am under a time restraint, and it is not 100% reliable*.

In summary: What may be causing this error, and is there a more reliable or permanent solution?

Comment: Did it come with 8.1 or did you upgrade? If so did you notice the problem on win 8?

Comment: I upgraded. And no, I didn't have the problem on Windows 8.